# Push notification on screen in Android

Tags: android, database, push-notification, daemon

I'm developing an application for a journal, which must allow the user to view the latest news on your Android smartphone, the news is retrieved directly from the database of the editorial.

Now i would implement a system that allows push notifications to alert user every time that someone insert a news in a certain database table, I'll explain:

In the database there is a table called "breaking news", every time that the editorial insert a new news in this table have to get a push notification to the user.

How can I do?

Do I have to use GCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use GCM system and your server has to send special GCM to every registered device on that event (every time that someone insert a news in a certain database table). The scenario is as follows:
every device which is using your app has to register on your server to be able to receive GCMs
if users are able to add news then your app has to send such news to the server and then server will send GCM to all devices.
it news adding is a task for some web service only then it a bit easier cuz you don't need to send it from app to server but still your server should send GCM on news adding event

Comment: The only ones authorized to post news are the members of the editorial staff of the newspaper, in particular: 

The staff put the news in the "breaking news", and the user receives a push notification.

Comment: This means the adding task is done via some web service (using special site page) or specialized software (it doesn't really matter) which "makes inserts" to news DataBase. Now, the trickiest part is to catch the insertion event and to run GCM broadcast

Comment: I suppose I should create a daemon that checks periodically on smartphone if there is a new item in the database, and notify it. 

On the server side I have no idea what I should do ..

Comment: If you are about to create "a daemon that checks periodically on smartphone if there is a new item in the database" (its a service u r talking about) then you don't need any GCM system. Just don't only check if any update available but dowload any new items. I call such systems "woodpecker". Better way is to create an event-based system and such event is DB update on your news server and also its a server's task to broadcast GCMs.